# How to deserialize included model properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm getting a string path (floated, dotted) for included table instead object with properties.
Where do I need to set the deserialization?

I tried receive value through object["object.id"] but it's not my choice

```
Model.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: Model2
        }],
        raw: true
    }).then(elems => {
        res.send(
            elems.map(elem => {
                return {
                    id: elem.id,
                    name: elem["model2table.model2name"]
                }
            })
        )
```

Expected: elem.model2table.model2name
Actual: elem["model2table.model2name"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `raw:true` from `findAll` params like this:

```
Model.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: Model2
        }]
    }).then(elems => {
        res.send(
            elems.map(elem => {
                return {
                    id: elem.id,
                    name: elem["model2table.model2name"]
                }
            })
        )
```

[Answer was founded here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4973)